# How to add manually Google API library to a project in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, api, google-maps

I'm doing small GPS project. Before I work on 32-bit laptop and I had option Target device:
2 x per every API. one was from Google and second from device. my laptop went down. I've bought new one 64-bit. I've installed every thing from beginning and now I don't have Google API option when I'm beginning new project.  And when I try to add any libraries to an existing project I have also not even a single one to pick. I've had reinstall everything 3 times and nothing, so now
I have only one option - add it manually to my project.

Where I can download Google Maps API for Android, and how to add them to my existing project manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install the Google API targets by opening the SDK and AVD manager. Either go to `Window -> SDK and AVD Manager` inside eclipse or start the `android` application from the `ANDROID_SDK\tools` folder.

When open, select `Available packages` on the left, then open the `Android Repository` tree. There should be various google APIs listed. Check the ones with the API levels you need and click `Install selected`. After everything went through, you can start a new project with the desired google APIs.